# Ember approach for setting controller computed property from action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new  to Ember and trying to follow the Data Down Action Up approach with my controller acting as the main parent 'component' with a number of components sending actions up to the controller to set values on models that will eventually trickle back down new value to the components. I know controllers are going away but I need this controller to hold all the state if you will...

I'm struggling with my approach in that I want to set a number of computed properties on my controller that watch model properties. Most difficult seemingly is setting the value of one of these computed properties that needs to set some other property when an action fires. Here is some of my controller (see updated exampled below, this left for reference):

```
//controllers/groupPlanning.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    groups: Ember.computed('model.@each.groups', function(){
        return this.get('model').get('groups');
    }),

    enrollmentGroup: Ember.computed('groups', function(){
        this.get('groups').forEach(function(group) {
            if (group.get('name') === 'Enrollment'){
                return group;
            }
        }):

    }),

    enrollmentGroupPercent: Ember.computed('enrollmentGroup', function() {
        var group = this.get('enrollmentGroup');
        return group.get('year') * this.get('someOtherNumber');
    }),

   ...

    actions: {
        setGroupYear: function(year){
            var group = this.get('enrollmentGroup');
            group.set('year', year);
            group.save();
        }
    }

});
```

**UPDATE**: The example above had a number flaws, the below code is to show the corrections per Lux's solution:

```
//controllers/groupPlanning.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    groups: Ember.computed('model.groups.[]', function(){
        return this.get('model.groups');
    }),

    enrollmentGroup: Ember.computed('groups', function(){
        return this.get('groups').findBy('name', 'Enrollment');
    }),

    enrollmentGroupPercent: Ember.computed('enrollmentGroup.year', 'someOtherNumber', function() {
        var group = this.get('enrollmentGroup');
        return group.year * this.get('someOtherNumber');
    }),

   ...

    actions: {
        setGroupYear: function(year){
            var group = this.get('enrollmentGroup');
            group.set('year', year);
            group.save();
        }
    }

});
```

Aside from asking if this approach seems reasonable, I'm having a problem actually setting the value of `enrollmentGroup` in my action:

`group.set('year', year);`

which throws and error of

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`

Any pointers here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `enrollmentGroup` computed property is returning anything, which would explain it being undefined. I suggest using [Ember.Array#find](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_find).

Comment: it does appear to return a Class when I console.log it out, however thanks for sharing the .find method that looks helpful :)

Comment: whats odd is that i can set the value from within the enrollmentGroup computed property with `group.set('name', 'newName');` but not from within my action hook. Also fixed a typo.. now using `group.get('name')`

Comment: Actually I dont think you need a computed property for groups. Just use model.groups? By the way, if you set a name of a group, the computed groups property will compute again. enrollmentGroup will be computed again and so on. Maybe what you need is just this.get('model.groups') and for the enrollmentGroup: this.get('model.groups').findBy({name':'Enrollment'})

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure I need computed properties in order to chain some reactions to any one of the `model.groups` attributes (like `year`) as I need to run some computations after any model changes, and that could affect computations from models that weren't changed. I'm thinking observer might be the approach per @Remi solution but still looking to avoid observers here and see if computed can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your dependency on the `enrollmentGroupPercent` is missing the `year`. Instead of

```
enrollmentGroupPercent: Ember.computed('enrollmentGroup', function() {
```

use

```
enrollmentGroupPercent: Ember.computed('enrollmentGroup.year', 'someOtherNumber', function() {
```

You definitely need the `year` because you modify it.

---

second, your problem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

this looks like `group` is `null`/`undefined` at this time! maybe check this with the debugger!

So definitly `enrollmentGroup` returns nothing. Maybe you just have no group with the name `Enrollment`. But I think you maybe ran into something more tricky.

I assume your `model` is an `ember-data` model, and `groups` an `hasMany` relationship.

This code does not make any sense:

```
groups: Ember.computed('model.@each.groups', function(){
    return this.get('model').get('groups');
}),
```

First I would recommend to replace `this.get('model').get('groups')` with `this.get('model.groups')` or `get(this, 'model.groups')` after setting `get` to `Ember.get`.

Then you use `@each` on `model`, which makes only sense if `model` is an array.

Probably you want to recompute the CP when groups are added/removed. In that case use `model.groups.[]` as dependency key. If you want to aggregate data from the groups, for example calculate a total you can use `model.groups.@each.quantity` and the CP will recalculate whenever a quantity on any group changes.

You actually need this if `name` could change, because then the list of groups does not change only the name so maybe you set the name later to `Enrollment`?

Now you should be able to replace

```
enrollmentGroup: Ember.computed('groups', function(){
```

with

```
enrollmentGroup: Ember.computed('groups.@each.name', function(){
```

but due to a [Bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475) in the current ember version this **will not work**!

It is important to understand then that the stores methods and model relationships don't return normal values but instances of `ArrayProxy`, `ObjectProxy`, `PromiseArray` and `PromiseObject`.

So actually `groups` is a PromiseArray of PromiseObjects. But you can unwrap the PromiseObjects in your `groups` CP:

```
groups: Ember.computed('model.groups.[]', function(){
    let promise = this.get('model.groups').then(groups => Ember.RSVP.all(groups));
    return DS.PromiseArray({promise});
}),
```

and then use `content` to observe the actual value:

```
enrollmentGroup: Ember.computed('groups.content.@each.name', function(){
    return this.get('groups').findBy('name', 'Enrollment');
}),
```

Now `enrollmentGroup` should always be up to date! So the only issue you might have is that you fire your action to early!

If you still have problems please provide a minimal example on [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com)!

Comment: thank you a whole lot! I have some learning to do here as you've covered a lot... but i'm feeling like this is getting me real close. I'll report back.

Comment: This ended up setting me straight. My example code was flawed as you noted. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the value of a computed propery, which won't work like this. I would suggest the [observer approach](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html):

```
enrollmentGroupObserver: Ember.observer('groups', function(){
        this.get('groups').forEach(function(group) {
            if (group.get('name') === 'Enrollment'){
                this.set('enrollmentGroup', group);
            }
        }):

    }),
enrollmentGroup: null,
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a potential, although I'm trying to find a way to not use the observer, to avoid the [observer tip-jar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PUX27RKCq0), is there anyway to do something similar as a computed property? I'll play with this and report back as well.